# Как ограничить ViewPager чтоб листать только вправо?

Tags: java, android

Можно ли как-то ограничить возможность пролистывания в одну из сторон? Нужно дать юзеру возможность листать только вправо, допустим.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно переопределить пару методов во `ViewPager`:

Для начала, создайте `enum`, который будет определять, в каком направлении `ViewPager` может работать:

```
public enum SwipeDirection {
    all, left, right, none ;
}
```

Теперь к самому `ViewPager`:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private float initialXValue;
    private SwipeDirection direction;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.direction = SwipeDirection.all; //поумолчанию разрешить листание в любом направлении
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.IsSwipeAllowed(event)) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.IsSwipeAllowed(event)) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean IsSwipeAllowed(MotionEvent event) {
        if(this.direction == SwipeDirection.all) //Усли разрешено все
            return true;

        if(direction == SwipeDirection.none ) //если листание запрещено 
            return false;

        //запоминаем начальную позицию тач ивента
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            initialXValue = event.getX();
            return true;
        }

        //рассчитываем направление свайпа, и запрещаем\разрешаем его
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            try {
                float diffX = event.getX() - initialXValue;
                if (diffX > 0 && direction == SwipeDirection.right ) {
                    // свайп влево запрещен
                    return false;
                }else if (diffX < 0 && direction == SwipeDirection.left ) {
                    // свайп вправо запрещен
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void setAllowedSwipeDirection(SwipeDirection direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }
}
```

Теперь добавляем его в разметку вместо обычного `ViewPager`

```
<тут_ваш_пакедж.CustomViewPager 
     android:id="@+id/customViewPager" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

И теперь в коде выставляем разрешение/запрет на свайп:

```
mViewPager.setAllowedSwipeDirection(SwipeDirection.right);
```

Так будет свайпать только вправо.

Answer (score 0):

подвесить к нему OnPageChangeListener, и следить что бы новое значение не оказалось больше (или меньше) текущего

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать переопределить метод [`performDrag`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#ViewPager.performDrag%28float%29) класса `ViewPager`:

```
private boolean performDrag(float x) {
    boolean needsInvalidate = false;

    final float deltaX = mLastMotionX - x;
    mLastMotionX = x;

    // начало нового кода
    if (deltaX < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    // окончание нового кода

    float oldScrollX = getScrollX();
    ...

}
```